# How do I go about adding email verification on my registration page? I'm trying to use sendgrid as my api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Here is my register-parent controller for reference

```
 [HttpPost("register-parent")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterParent(Parent parent, [FromForm] string password)
    {
        var roleName = "Parent";
        var roleExists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
        if (!roleExists)
        {
            var role = new IdentityRole(roleName);
            var result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Redirect(
                    $"/Registration/ParentRegistration?error=Failed to create role for parent!");
            }
        }
        
        var signInResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(parent, password);

        if (signInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(parent, roleName);
            // await _signInManager.SignInAsync(parent, true);

            // Send email confirmation
            return Redirect($"/email/{parent.Id}");
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect(
                $"/Registration/ParentRegistration?error={signInResult.Errors.FirstOrDefault().Description}");
        }
    }
```

This code was just given to my to edit/update. I am not sure about the previous email verification they used if there is any.

Haven't tried anything yet. Just asking for some help and some tips on how to start.

Comment: We use MailKit library to send out emails in our website. Here's a sample for sending emails using MailKit. Hope it helps: https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-send-email/